# Controller always is null from view using Html.BeginForm() ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to get multiple instances of my model objects sent to the controller as a list but for some reason, I always get the null exception where nothing is actually posted when submit is pressed.

My textbox works fine, but I can't find why or how these values are sent to the controller and why my code doesn't work.

This is my View:

```html
@model MVCModel.Models.Student

 <b>Result</b>    @ViewBag.s <br />
  
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tbody id="GenaratorList">
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Name: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</td>
            <td>Enter Age: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addGenarator()" /></td>
        </tr>
     <tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
}

<script>
    count = 0;
    function addGenarator() {
        var Name = $('#Name').val();
        var Age = $('#Age').val();
        var Student = "studentModels[" + count + "]";
        $('#GenaratorList').append('<tr><td><input id="' + Student + '.Name" Name="' + Student + '.Name" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Name + '"></td><td><input id="' + Student + '.Age" Age="' + Student + '.Age" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + Age + '"></td></tr>');
        $('#Name,#Age').val('');
        count++;
    }
</script>
```

This is my Controller:

```html
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Form(List<Student> s)
        {
          
            return View("Index");
        }
```

This is my Model:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCModel.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sending a single Student object from the browser, not a `List<Student>`

Comment: Also, `ViewBag.s = Student[0].Name;` ??

Comment: MVCModel.Models.Student shouldn't be List<MVCModel.Models.Student> your model is an object of student class and you are expecting a list of student Object in your controller

Comment: @adiga Thank you, I'm new to MVC, how would I change it from a single object to a list of them

Comment: `ActionResult Form(Student s)`

Comment: @Iswar Thank you so much ;) That was one of the things that wasn't working

Comment: Hi @Iswar, can you write it as an answer as it helps the Post Owner. So Post Owner can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and it would be helpful for the future readers. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is repetitive.
I answered this question in the following link, you can use it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72697060/error-when-passing-list-of-objects-from-controller-to-view-using-html-beginform/72698700#72698700